# Чему равно (7^-5) mod 17

Tags: математика, теория-чисел

Мне нужно решить данный пример, ответом которого должно быть натуральное число - найти значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал решать так: `7` в степени `-5` - это дробь `1/16807`, но дальше ничего не могу сделать - эту дробь никак не поделишь с остатком на 17, чтобы получилось целое число.

Comment: вы ничего не забыли? может `(7^5) mod 17` или `(7^x - 5) mod 17`?

Comment: Я имел в виду семь в степени минус 5, и это всё по модулю 17

Comment: Без минуса я понимаю как решить, а с минусом никак целое число не получить?

Comment: Символ `^` это точно возведение в степеь? В языках C/C++ так обозначается побитовая операция XOR ("исключающее или")

Comment: Почитал комментарии. Огорчился ужасно... Недаром у меня в профиле написано "...*я так стар, что помню те времена, когда программисты знали математику*..." И это еще при том, что по образованию я вообще-то физик :( Люди, **сравнение по модулю** и **остаток от деления** - это две большие разницы!

Comment: @Harry Прошу прощения, если вам не трудно, можете указать ошибку в логике моего ответа?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Вы путаете сравнение по модулю и получение остатка - здесь надо использовать не обычную арифметику, а модульную... Посмотрите по ссылке из моего ответа статью в Википедии.

Comment: Сравнение целых чисел по модулю - это и есть ответ на вопрос, дают ли они один и тот же остаток при делении. В чём большие разницы, Карл?

Comment: Короче, я понял) 1/a в кольце m, если определено, то всегда остаётся целым числом, на то оно и кольцо)

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо за формулировку! (Я не прикалываюсь, если что - как у физика, у меня всегда было тяжело с точной математической терминологией...)

Comment: @vp_arth для функций `f⁻¹ ∘ f = id`, для матриц `M⁻¹ ∙ M = I`, для сравнения по модулю `x⁻¹x ≡ 1 (mod m)`. Т.е. понятие обратного элемента обобщается на разные сущности, и далеко не всегда оно имеет хоть какое-либо отношение к делению.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ну, обратим 7 по модулю 17. Можно поиграться подбором, можно воспользоваться тем, что 7 и 17 взаимно простые и использовать функцию Эйлера (см., например, [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E#%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)) - в результате при обращении 7 по модулю 17 получаем 5 (чтоб было понятнее: 7*5 == 1 (mod 17)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше просто ищем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]