# Как вычислить обратный элемент по модулю

Tags: математика

решал задачки и столкнулся с проблемой,

```
Найдите 4 в −1 степени(mod11)
```

Впринципе на простых числах я понял

```
2^(−1)≡3(mod5)
```

А тут застрял думаю что получится 44

Comment: 2^(-1) == 3 % 5;
0.5 == 3;
false

Comment: Неясно, что вам требуется. Может быть, `обратный элемент (в кольце) по модулю`?

Comment: Найти 4^(-1) mod(11)

Comment: Именно так, обратный элемент в кольце по модулю

Comment: Для таких маленьких значений - хоть перебором :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1194004/195342

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вычисление обратного элемента в кольце по модулю с использованием расширенного алгоритма Евклида ([max_algo](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/reverse_element))

```
def gcdex(a, b):
    if a == 0 :
        return b,0,1
    gcd,x,y = gcdex(b%a, a)
    return gcd, y - (b//a) * x, x

def invmod(a, m):
    g, x, y = gcdex (a, m)
    return None if g > 1 else (x % m + m) % m

print(invmod(4,11)) # result 3    (4 * 3) % 11 = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

В общем случае ответ @MBo про расширенный алгоритм Евклида работает в большом классе колец, так называемых Евклидовых кольцах. Например, в кольцах многочленов над полями.

Но в частном случае циклических групп, когда известно разложение порядка группы на множители, можно пользоваться [теоремой Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)). В вашем случае `4^10 == 1 (mod 11)`, следовательно `4^(-1) == 4^9 (mod 11) == 3 (mod 11)`.

Чуть более обще. Пусть `n` - модуль, `phi(n)` - [функция Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) для `n`, тогда `a^(-1) == a^(phi(n)-1) (mod n)`.

Например, `4^(-1) (mod 21) == 4^11 (mod 21) == 16 (mod 21)`