# Как вычислить обратный элемент по модулю c#

Tags: c#

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать алгоритм на c#, который находил бы обратный элемент по модулю при вводе числа и самого модуля. Обратным к числу a по модулю m называется такое число b, что:
a*b=1(mod m) и его нередко обозначают через a^{-1}.
Интересует алгоритм, который бы быстро работал с большими числами типа BigInteger. Нужно для реализации шифра.
Нашла код (скорее всего python), работает хорошо, но не разобралась и не смогла переписать его на c# [смотрела тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1298164/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E/1298196#1298196)

```
def gcdex(a, b):
  if a == 0 :
    return b,0,1
  gcd,x,y = gcdex(b%a, a)
  return gcd, y - (b//a) * x, x #здесь целочисленное деление

def invmod(a, m):
  g, x, y = gcdex (a, m)
  return None if g > 1 else (x % m + m) % m

print(invmod(4,11)) #result 3   (4 * 3) % 11 = 1
```

Comment: что такое "обратный элемент"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понял суть задачи, для меня модуль числа - это его мантисса. То есть математический термин. Наверное имелся в виду остаток от деления?

Я не знаю, что за язык (наверное python), но попробую

```
static (int, int, int) gcdex(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return (b, 0, 1);
    (int gcd, int x, int y) = gcdex(b % a, a);
    return (gcd, y - (b / a) * x, x);
}

static int invmod(int a, int m)
{
    (int g, int x, int y) = gcdex(a, m);
    return g > 1 ? 0 : (x % m + m) % m;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(invmod(4, 11));
}
```

Comment: в вопросе речь идет про [сравнение по модулю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E) - вполне себе математический термин

Comment: @aepot, супер, спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, буду знать.